# Method for splitting string into separate cells in Sheets / App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to split a string into separate cells, but the order of substrings will be different to how it appears in the string originally. Not all parts of the string are necessary and the length of each substring isn't static. I managed to achieve something workable on a separate project where the substring lengths were static using lastIndexOf but it was incredibly clunky.

I'm hoping that someone could point me to a better way of approaching the problem.

Each string of data will look like this:

```
01|020202|03|0404040404|05|0606060606|
```

My previous code was equivalent to this:

```
function splitString() {

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
 var input = sheet.getRange(2,4).getValue(); 

 var data1 = input.substring(input.lastIndexOf("!")-5,input.lastIndexOf("|")-1);
 var data2 = input.substring(input.lastIndexOf("|")-10, data1);

 // etc.

 sheet.getRange(3,2).setValue(data1);
 sheet.getRange(4,2).setValue(data2);

 // etc.

}
```

Can anybody suggest a better method for doing this? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks that you need that each element be on the same column on differents rows. Use [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) then convert the resulting array into a 2D array.

The following example, for simplicity built on "pure" JavaScript, use forEach but there are several other ways to do the same.

```js
var s = '01|020202|03|0404040404|05|0606060606|';
var t = s.split('|');
var output = [];
t.forEach(function(q){
 output.push([q]);
});
console.info(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Look thru the various string API methods for Javascript on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String). There should be one to split a string into an array using a delimiter (the pipe "|" character in your case). Then checkout the [`setValues`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object)) method of the Range class which allows you to set a series of cells using an array with a single method call.

Answer (score 1):

```
function splitString() {
  var theSplitString 
  ="01|020202|03|0404040404|05|0606060606|".split("|");
  Logger.log(theSplitString);
  // the result is an array [01, 020202, 03, 0404040404, 05, 0606060606, ]
}`
```

Then as suggested use the range.setValues